# Android 30 Days From Todays Date

Tags: java, android, datetime, parse-platform

I need my application VIP feature to expire 30 days from today, I will store the current date in the application config. How will I check if the VIP feature has expired ? I don't mind if the user changed the clock back and the app works.

When user Activate a VIP features

```
mCurrentUser.setVip();
mCurrentUser.SaveInBackgroud();

// in want to also set StartDate and EndDate
```

Then to verify if the date saved in mCurrentUser endDate is igual to today

```
// set user to no VIP! like

mCurrentUser.setNoVip();
mCurrentUser.SaveInBackgroud();
```

Comment: What attempt have you made using the plentiful date/time handling classes and libraries available? We are not a code-writing service.

Comment: I would prefer to see you write a timestamp in the timezone of your server to the database along with the username.  This avoids the problem of the user changing his local clock.

Comment: e.g. `System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(30)` then check with current time. That's exactly 30 * 24 hours so it can be perceived a little different from "in 30 days" which usually caps at 00:00.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get date after 30 days from given date by following method.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(startDate);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 30);
Date expDate = c.getTime();
```

After that you can compare both dates.

```
if(startDate.after(expiate)){
   // Your time expired do your logic here.
}
```

if true then time is expired.

Answer (score 2):

You should not store such information locally at all in this case. Instead, add field "activationDate" in Users table. Then do query for it and then do calculations locally.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to expire exactly on the second in 30d he started the vip, you can use this:

to start the timer:

```
SharedPreferences.editor editor1= getSharedPreferences("vipexpire", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

                    editor1.putInt("starttime", (int) System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
                    editor1.apply();
```

in onCreate of your mainActivity, to check every time user opens app if the time is over:

```
SharedPreferences vipTimer= getSharedPreferences("vipexpire", MODE_PRIVATE);
int startTime= vipTimer.getInt("starttime", 0);
int currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
int timeofVip= currentTime - startTime; //calculate the time of his VIP-being time
if (timeofVip>= 2592000)  //2592000 is 30 days in seconds
{
//30 days over, update user to non-vip
}
```

This method is also nice to have when storing the timestamp on a server or if you want to have an accurate countdown displayed in your app!